# Build error: The "ResolveTargetingPackAssets" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to build a dotnet core project on a linux machine.

Build fails with the following error:

> : error MSB4018: The "ResolveTargetingPackAssets" task failed
>   unexpectedly.
>   [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProject/MyProject/MyProject.csproj]
>   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(264,5)

I don't know what to do, can someone please advise.

See csproj below.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.30" />
        <PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http" Version="2.4.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http.Xml" Version="1.6.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="LazyCache" Version="2.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.7.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.5.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore" Version="3.0.13" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Security\" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please, share `MyProject.csproj` file. Did you check that you are targeting the right SDK?

Comment: Thanks @PavelAnikhouski, I've updated the question to include the .csproj

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?